# string letters validation

Tags: c#, .net

I am confused about strings and int. and can't validate a name to be without numbers and strange charchters. a-z and A-Z are fine. I understand the do while loop and use of a sentinel. I seen Regex on here but it doesn't work in my code for some reason unknown to me. I would rather go with a simple solution that I can understand it. I have validation of int in my code working great, but validating the name gets bool, and  int errors.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int age;
        double mileage;
        string strInput, name;
        bool isValid;

        DisplayApplicationInformation();

        DisplayDivider("Start Program");
        Console.WriteLine();

        DisplayDivider("Get Name");
        strInput = GetInput("your name");
        name = strInput;
        Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
        Console.WriteLine();

        do
        {
        DisplayDivider("Get Age");
        strInput = GetInput("your age");
        isValid = int.TryParse(strInput, out age);
        if (!isValid || (age <= 0))
        {
            isValid = false;
            Console.WriteLine("'" + strInput + "' is not a valid age entry. Please retry...");
        }
        }while (!isValid);
        Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + age);
        //age = int.Parse(strInput);
        //Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + age);
        Console.WriteLine();

        do
        {
        DisplayDivider("Get Mileage");
        strInput = GetInput("gas mileage");
        isValid = double.TryParse(strInput, out mileage);
        if (!isValid || (mileage <= 0))
        {
            isValid = false;
            Console.WriteLine("'" + strInput + "' is not a valid mileage entry. Please retry...");
        }
        } while (!isValid);
        Console.WriteLine("Your age is: " + mileage);
        //mileage = double.Parse(strInput);
        //Console.WriteLine("Your car MPT is: " + mileage);

        TerminateApplication();
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried to validate the name.

Comment: Can you further explain the errors you mention?  Are you getting actual exceptions in the code?  If so, what are they, where do they happen, and what is the state of the data when they happen?  If no actual errors, what is the indication of error?  What is the expected behavior vs. the observed behavior, and where in the code do the two deviate?

Comment: If you can introduce yourself to Regex, it is SO much simpler than what you are trying to attempt ;)

Comment: `"Your age is: " + mileage` - it pays to use appropriate names.

Comment: Are you wanting to validate if a name contains on Alpha Characters then Validated = true if Name has AlphaNumeric or other Charcters like $@#%@!()* for example then False.. look at the Char.All method if you need a simple example I can post one for you.. works fine for me all the time..  Also Post and example of the Failed Name in question...

Comment: "^[A-Za-z\s]+$" would be the regex pattern to match a string, with spaces ;)

Comment: @Craig1231: for checking if only "normal" letters (a to z) are in a string, you don't need a regex. It even wouldn't make things much simpler.

Comment: I donT agree @craig1231. It s hard to get and control for beginners. Hard to identify the errors too.. I think what you need is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181419/c-sharp-newbie-verifying-that-a-string-contains-only-letters

Comment: Why do I feel like the OP's questions should require the `Homework` tag?

Comment: You guys are very fast in responding, thanks for that. I used the same exact idea for fet age and get mileage to validate get name. I almost grasp that I have to convert for the numbers. I am confused because get name doesn't have to be converted. I like to understand Regex but I am too new to C#.

Comment: @Zortkun, its one line of code, how can it be confusing??

Comment: @craig1231 what s funnier is that the link i post is also regex :P well , i still think regex is confusing in the beginning :)

but if he wants to use smth he d understand and help learn programming, I d suggest some solution like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1181425/494659 ... though i admit it s not the best idea..

Comment: @Zortkun, I agree, getting the pattern correct can be a pain! ;) Its best to start early

Comment: where you are doing strInput = GetInput("your name");         name = strInput;         Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);         Console.WriteLine();  you need to check at that point if the name is valid does this make sense after you add the Replace().All(Char.....) code

Comment: may I alter your code in the example that you have posted at the top so that you can understand what I am talking about..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Regex that works for what you want

```
        Regex reg = new Regex("^[A-Za-z]+$");
        do
        {
            DisplayDivider("Get Name");
            strInput = GetInput("your Name");
            isValid = reg.IsMatch(strInput);
            if (!isValid)
            {
                isValid = false;
                Console.WriteLine("'" + strInput + "' is not a valid name entry. Please retry...");
            }
        } while (!isValid);
```

Basically, it says, "Match start of the string (^ means start) and only letter till end of string ($ means end of string) and there must be 1 or more letters (that's the +)"

Probably the easiest

Now, this is assuming of course that you don't want "Firstname Lastname" because that would mean there is a space involved.  Let me know if you need spaces for name separations.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Regex' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @badboy Right click on "Regex" and then hover over "Resolve", it should display using System.Text.RegularExpressions. Add that reference, and you should be good.

Comment: I didn't know about that, awesome! I had a school lab that i fininshes already. I am just revisiting to learn validation on my own. You guys are great. I hope that I canunderstand c# like you guys and contribute back to beginners. Thank you.

Comment: I went with joe_coolish regex solution and had to resolve the errors messages by adding some stuff to the using area. My validation works and it was only for the sake of knowing how to. I am greatful and hope to give back someday when I learn more. Thanks!

Comment: No prob :) Glad I could help! +1s are always great too! :P

Answer (score 5):

As much as I would recommend you to use a simple Regex, you pointed out you wanted a different solution.

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181419/c-sharp-newbie-verifying-that-a-string-contains-only-letters), the first answer is a Regex solution but the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181488/1157493) might answer your question:

```
bool result = input.All(Char.IsLetter);
```

As pointed out by Chris Lively, if you allow a space in the name then you can validate with:

```
bool result = input.Replace(" ", "").All(Char.IsLetter);
```

Comment: This would return false for example var input = "Marry Had A Little Lamb"; the spaces are not letters

Comment: +1 for the answer @DJKRAZE - that wasn't in the specs to allow for spaces

Comment: @DJKRAZE: In that case use: bool result = input.Replace(" ", "").All(Char.IsLetter);  Still easier than a regex

Comment: Good point @DJKRAZE, didn't think about that. +1 for Chris Lively's solution.

Comment: Regex is not hard per say..it more or less boils down to understanding the Pattern and getting the darn thing in the right order.. 6 of one half Dozen of the other...

Comment: DJKRAZE thank you for helping and all the others. I am trying to comment and thank everyone for the help. I used regex and someone told me how to resolve it and add the line on the top using Sytem.Test.RegularExpressions...Regex is now  my best friend.

Answer (score 0):

Bad boy @Chris Lively's suggestion is more of the lines you want something easy to read and not RegEx

```
   bool result = strInput.Replace(" ", "").All(Char.IsLetter); 

  if you are wanting to do it the long way with a forloop then look at this example

for (int i = 0; i < strinput.Length; i++)
{
   //if this character isn't a letter and it isn't a Space then return false
   //because it means this isn't a valid alpha string
   if (!(char.IsLetter(strinput[i])) && (!(char.IsWhiteSpace(strinput[i]))))
   return false;
}
```

Comment: DisplayDivider("Get Name");
            strInput = GetInput("your name");
            bool result = strInput.Replace(" ", "").All(Char.IsLetter);  
            name = strInput;
            Console.WriteLine("Your name is: " + name);
            Console.WriteLine();

Comment: do you have that wrapped around an if to display name only if valid you need to post the exact code in a more readable fashion in your original post can you do that

Comment: I didn't get the code to work with@Chris Lively's suggestion. It was simple and exacltly what I asked for. I will play with this solution. I also figure out how to use regex and won't ever forget it. I appreciate that you offerred exaclty what I wanted and also the regex way. I have more tools in my arsenal now. Thanks everyone!