# Keep only elements of a list that have only letters

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<string>` that contains some elements that have non-letter characters. For instance, I might have `#232353;` which doesn't contain any letter at all, or I might have `SomeText,SomeOtherText` and that element contains a comma, which is also not a letter. How can I remove these elements using linq? Something like this:

```
MyList = MyList.Where(...)
```

Thanks.

Comment: See [Verifying that a string contains only letters in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181419/verifying-that-a-string-contains-only-letters-in-c-sharp) and [How to remove elements from a generic list while iterating over it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582285/how-to-remove-elements-from-a-generic-list-while-iterating-over-it). Learn to break up your problems in smaller parts and you'll see all questions have been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is on a `List<string>` you can use the `RemoveAll` method to remove all the values that match a specific predicate

```
MyList.RemoveAll(s => s.Any(c => !Char.IsLetter(c)));
```

Comment: +1 good option. Also you can use `FindAll` method of list, but that will create new list of results, as my answer does

Comment: What is the implication of saying "Since this is on a List<string>"?

Comment: @frenchie this means that the remove can be done in place without having to create a new collection.  The `List<T>` type has methods Add / Remove which directly modify the collection.  Types like `IEnumerable<T>` on the other hand have extension methods which are remove like but create a new collection.  This means you end up with syntax like `e = e.Where(x => ...)`.

Comment: Ah ok, so in one case we end up with 2 lists where one is reassigned to the original reference and the other is garbage-collected while with methods that are part of the List type we only keep one list. Is that about right?

Comment: @frenchie that is correct

Comment: Ok, cool; learning everyday; thanks.

Comment: One more quick question: is a List<T> technically a type of IEnumerable that has additional methods?

Comment: @frenchie yes.  I'd phrase it as the follownig. `List<T>` is a type with methods and properties that implements `IEnumerable<T>` (as well as `IList<T>`)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`Char.IsLetter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyxz6h5w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if all characters in string are letters:

```
MyList = MyList.Where(s => s.All(Char.IsLetter)).ToList();
```

Comment: Ok, thanks: it looks good but it's saying it can't convert an IEnumerable<string> to a List<string>

Comment: @frenchie sorry, missed that thing - just add `ToList()` call to create new `List<string>` from filtered strings

Comment: What's the "behind-the-scene" difference between your answer and Jared's answer?

Comment: @frenchie if you need to hold filtered strings in same list, then it's better to remove them from list, instead of creating new list. If you need only enumerate result, than there is no need to modify original list or create new list. But if you need results as `List<string>` then use Jared's option