# Allow only alphabetic name in text box in c#

Tags: c#

I need to allow user only to enter alphabetic name in text box e.g jhon or Kamran Khan. I already got info from different links but nothing is working yet.
In my code text box get those values which are started with numbers e.g 3kamran but i need not to allow 3 or any other number.
i am using c# windows app and my code looks like.

```
private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtName.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        txtName.Text.Remove(txtName.Text.Length - 1);
        txtName.Clear();
        txtName.Focus();
     }
}
```

Comment: Remove the `^`, although this won't allow you to enter double barrel names - i.e Mary-Jane (or any names with umlauts etc in them)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Verifying that a string contains only letters in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181419/verifying-that-a-string-contains-only-letters-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Try putting an @ symbol is your regex match and trim the textbox text, i.e. Regex.IsMatch(txtName.Text.Trim(), @"^[a-zA-Z]+$")

Comment: Make an SCII array containing all walid characters and then look if there is a non valid charracter.

Comment: you should be using the key_pressed event, and check Key ==  IsAlpha property set the handle true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

    //here is the problem add ! in font 

    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName)) // This will prevent exception when textbox is empty   
    {
    if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtName.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Valid Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtName.Text.Remove(txtName.Text.Length - 1);
            txtName.Clear();
            txtName.Focus();
         }
    }
   }
```

Comment: When i entered invalid name then it works fine but when text box came to empty then it will threw an error "StartIndex cannot be less than zero.
Parameter name: startIndex" i think this is due to text length. Then what to do next to resolve it.

Comment: can you elaborate with example, from what i have understood, remove this txtName.Text.Remove(txtName.Text.Length - 1); from code if its not required.

Comment: Now this also check on empty text box and show message box for two times.

Comment: enclose the if condition inside this check if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtName.Text)) // This will prevent exception when textbox is empty { // your code inside it. }

Comment: Check txtName.Text for being null or whitespace.. I have forgotten to add .Text in the check

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, "^[a-zA-Z]"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters");
    textBox1.Text.Remove(textBox1.Text.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is, that you also want to support spaces (like in your example `Kamran Khan`). In that case your expression needs to be:

```
[a-zA-Z ]+
```

(Take care for the whitespace before the closing bracket)

Also doing a `txtName.Text.Remove(txtName.Text.Length - 1);` is very fraguile. What happens, if the user enters a digit at the beginning of the text?

Answer (score 1):

You would be better to not use regex, and instead just check if the string has any digits in it.

One solution to this is as follows which uses `System.Linq`

```
if(txtName.Text.Any(char.IsDigit))
    // Contains numbers
```

As a side note: it isn't completely illegal to give your child a name that contains a number

Examples of names that your current regex won't match

- Mary-Jane
- Frédéric
- März

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to get Regex free version then the simplest way is to handle the TextChanged event as you did, but check what's been typed. Will work also for 'paste'.

```
string oldText = string.Empty;
private void txtName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtName.Text.All(chr => char.IsLetter(chr)))
    {
        oldText = txtName.Text;
        txtName.Text = oldText;

        txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        txtName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    }
    else
    {
        txtName.Text = oldText;
        txtName.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        txtName.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    }
    txtName.SelectionStart = txtName.Text.Length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is

```
private void TextBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     e.Handled = char.IsLetter((char) e.Key);
}
```