# C# Regex won't find the matches

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to detect whether my string contains the alphabets (a-z & A-Z), and I obtained my answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1181419/6573544) post. But not all string works as expected, take 8+a as an example:

```
string expression = "8+a";
            if (Regex.IsMatch(expression, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$") == true)
                true;
            else
                false;
```

This returns false which suppose to be true. How do I make this return true. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the anchors. Or better, do not use a regex if you just need to check if a string contains a single letter, use `if (s.Any(char.IsLetter)) {...}`

Comment: ^ anchors as in the `^` and `$`.

Comment: Your regex checks if it *only* contains alphabets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` Anchors your regex to the start of the string.

`$` Anchors to the end of the string.

Remove those and your regex will work.

Also, there is no need to compare a `bool` value to `true` because it is done automatically.