# I want to test the value of the Text Box to make sure it only has letters

Tags: c#

I am trying to test if a name text box contains only letters. I want to test the value of the Text Box to make sure it only has letters. Currently the code accepts numbers & symbols.
How can I do this?

```
     private void ProductionWorkerData(ProductionWorker objPW)
        {
            // Temporary variables to hold the employeeNum, shiftNum, & payRate.
         //   string employeeName;   
            int employeeNum;
            int shiftNum;
            decimal payRate;

            #region Check employeeName.
            // Check if employeeNameTextBox is empty or not.
            if (employeeNameTextBox.Text != "")
            {
                // Assign employeeName object to employeeNameTextBox.
                objPW.EmployeeName = employeeNameTextBox.Text;
            }// end if loop.
                // Check if employeeName is a string only.(No numbers or symbols)
                if (employeeNameTextBox.Text  )
                {
                    // Display and error message invalid Employee Name.
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Employee Name.");

                }// end else if loop.
            else
            {
                // Display message to "Enter Employee Name.
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter an Employee name.");

            }// end else statement.
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1181426/8161471 for regex checks.

Comment: When you say letters, I assume you only want to allow the Latin alphabet? What about accents such as à, û, etc.?

Comment: I am still new to coding. I'm not sure how to apply this to my code. Can someone please help?

Comment: use `Regex.Matches` in C# or read about it from google